# PHP Variable Encryption

Tags: php, encryption, base64, encode, sha1

I have the following code that creates an encryption in PHP:

```
$password = "helloworld";
$passwordupper = strtoupper($password);
$passwordencode = mb_convert_encoding($passwordupper, 'UTF-16LE');
$passwordsha1 = hash("SHA1", $passwordencode);
$passwordbase64 = base64_encode($passwordsha1);
```

The instructions I have from the system I'm trying to connect to states:

> The encoding process for passwords is: first convert to uppercase, then Unicode it in little-endian UTF 16, then SHA1 it then base64 encode it.

I think I'm doing something wrong in my code.  Any ideas?

Comment: sha1 hash can either be raw binary, or a base64-encoded string to begin with. e.g. `$raw = sha1($string, true)` v.s. `$encoded = sha1($string)`. you'd better try both variants, because you may be double-base64-encoding.

Comment: Perfect Marc B, that did the trick!

Comment: I strongly recommend using built-in `password_hash()` method (PHP >= 5.5) instead of `hash()` http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer solved by Marc B above in comments:

> sha1 hash can either be raw binary, or a base64-encoded string to
>   begin with. e.g. $raw = sha1($string, true) v.s. $encoded =
>   sha1($string). you'd better try both variants, because you may be
>   double-base64-encoding.